# Why is my map so... messed up?

Tags: terraria

See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

You can click it to enlarge it. As you can see, there's something... very wrong with it. Some parts of the world are shifted around, caves aren't in the right spot, etc.

Here's a closer-up view (click to enlarge):

[image: another screenshot]

I've found out that by saving and quitting, sometimes the map is fixed (sometimes it's just messed up in a different way again, like this one:

[image: one more]

It stays that way until the next time I save and quit, and then it happens again (in an even different way).

This has been happening since the update. It's extremely annoying; how can I fix it?

**EDIT**: I've noticed that sometimes when scrolling in large map view, the map will mess up in a different way or become fixed. I have not yet found a reliable way of fixing the map, though

Comment: `This has been happening since the update.` Well, the map only exists since the update, so maybe it's broken?

Comment: @Nolonar `maybe it's broken` ...you don't say? :P Yes, just wanted to clarify that it's always been this way.

Comment: @All Please don't use tick marks (reserved for code snippets) as quotation marks! Quotation marks will do nicely.

Comment: Might be having some lighting problems. Light is...finnicky even in the best-built games, where it is less vital to the mechanics of said game, and it's entirely possible that your map is getting jumbled because of mixed lighting...not knowing exactly HOW the map works, I can't say if this is true or not. But it's a best guess.

Comment: @Zibbobz It's not a lighting issue; Terraria doesn't have a lighting model, just using a revealed/hidden tiles display model. Besides which, there are missing floors and walls in the lit parts of that screenshot.

Comment: If the way it's messed up changes as you scroll around, it sounds like a bug in the rendering engine or a problem with the videocard. Shifting displays usually mean the game is writing its graphics to the wrong places at the wrong time or the card is displaying the wrong parts of video memory. Are graphics drivers up-to-date?

Comment: @Seven I'll check when I'm at my computer (using phone right now)

Comment: It's just the map that's messed up, the actual world is fine, right? Have you tried it again with the most recent update?

Comment: @Seven Yes (very late reply, sorry, forgot to reply earlier :-P)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your map file got corrupted somehow. The safest thing to do, unfortunately, is to remove the map file and start over.

Quit Terraria, then find your Terraria player files on your computer. These should be at `My Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players`.

If you have more than one player, open the folder that corresponds with the player that has the map problem. There will be one or more files in the player folder with names like `490810387.map`. These are all map files, one for each world.

If you have more than one, you might be able to determine which one to delete using the modified date on the file. If you just played the world that has the broken map, the modified date on that map file will be the most recent.

Deleting the map file will reset the map for the player in that world, and it will start filling in again the next time you play.

Comment: No... the map is fine, but just the minimap isn't working. This problem happens on all worlds including new ones, so...

Comment: That's what he's saying. Mini-map data is stored in the player files - he's saying you need to delete the mini-map data from the player so you can fill it in again. The world file is totally separate and seems to be working fine.